# Iphone sdk: Drawing a continuous line in Quartz with an "overlap"

Tags: iphone, ios4, quartz-graphics

From a source of points im drawing a line that crosses over itself using this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake([delegate getTileWidth], [delegate getTileWidth]));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[delegate GetColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, [delegate getBrushWidth]);   
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xpath[0], ypath[0]);

for (int i = 0; i <= ([CurrentLine count]-2); i++) {

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,  xpath[i],ypath[i]);

}
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

The drawing is working just fine, but if i draw it with a alpha and the lines "crosses" itself there is no overlap.

What im getting:
(The yellow lines and numbers are for debugging)

[What im getting](http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/8760/photo1nx.png)

What i want:
Compared to the first image there is a clear "overlap" where the line crosses itself
[What i want](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/4026/photobe.png)

So im wonering where i can find the setting to allow "overlap", i have read around on the CGContext refrence page and tried tons of different settings. So i think im lost...

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Forgot to add link descriptions, sorry :( First time using StackOverflow.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the missing links. While you're at it you might also want to tag the question with iphone (gets more views than iphone-sdk-4.0). Welcome to SO.

Comment: What is xPath and the current line ?

Comment: Please consider sharing if you found an answer :)